# Is it possible to use godaddy only for domain registration or transfer?

Tags: domain-registration, godaddy, landing-page, domain-transfer, wix

In [migrating](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/136057/114967) a domain to godaddy from ionos, is it required to also create a web page?

I'm only interested in maintaining the registration and wouldn't even want an "under construction" website.  It just seems that godaddy pops up wix or different templates, which doesn't interest me.

Comment: why would you choose godaddy?

Comment: I think there’s probably 100s of better options than Go Daddy. Why are you migrating?

Comment: just cost @user253751 and Tim, as ionos wants $$ just to renew a dormant domain.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders okay well you should know that GoDaddy has a terrible reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use them just for domain registration and no other services.  Simply register the domain and don't buy any hosting.

If the registrar places their own advertisement on the domain, edit DNS and delete the `A Record`.

Or you could change the nameservers to somewhere that has a free site and have a blank page...or nothing.

Comment: what is meant by "go into dns"?  if you would elaborate as to how that relates to godaddy.

Comment: Your nameservers point somewhere.  That is where DNS is hosted.  You need to edit DNS as I described. At godaddy https://godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-records-680

Comment: Also it is totally legit, and every registrars should be able to do it (and are even required for gTLD ones per ICANN contracts), to have a domain name without any nameservers.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah, but I didn't want to complicate it and also, maybe OP would learn a little about DNS ;o)

Comment: This answer is correct, but Godaddy doesn't make it easy.  They won't let you do anything without asking you to add all sorts of add-on services like private registration, website hosting, and email hosting.   Every time that you buy, transfer, or renew a domain expect to click through several screens of "no thanks, I don't want all the extras."