# How are GoDaddy DNS settings manually configured?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-transfer

What are the mechanical or technical steps to use GoDaddy [strictly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/136059/114967) for domain registration for a dormant domain?

At present, not looking for hosting.  E-mail service is preferred, I'm currently using `alpine` for text only `IMAP` access.  However, that's tangential to the question at hand.

**So I would just want the domain registration to transfer to GoDaddy and be renewed without any web hosting.**

I'm particularly intrigued as to the mention of DNS in the initial question.  I might choose a different hosting provider, for example.  What's the relevance to DNS in **this** context?

I need to go "into the DNS" somehow?  Not following that at all.  Looking for detailed technical expanded answers on that point.  Karma points for employing impenetrable jargon unnecessarily.

Comment: As in other questions you are still not giving the domain or even the TLD. FWIW in gTLDs, registrars are required by ICANN to respect owner wishes on which nameservers to use, and no nameservers is a valid configuration as any other, while registrars may push you more towards "parking" by default for obvious reasons. Anyway that means you should be able to choose any DNS providers. ccTLDs should be similar in owners' rights. Note that all (most probably) registrars are ALSO DNS providers, but those are 2 separate jobs and you can use any registrar with any DNS provider.

Comment: Your question implies you musunderstand Domains/DNS  Domain registration and DNS are 2 differnt - albeit related things. You need DNS for email to work, even if you dont have a website. (You want at least an MX & mail exchange - record set up in DNS).

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand about the question, in that, so far as I know, my understanding of DNS and MX records is sufficient for the purpose.  Not sure how to clarify the question.  My intent is to only "park" the registration, I'm not using any hosting at the moment.  I happen to use the e-mail service which comes along with the domain registration, which is convenient.  What am I not understanding about what's not understood about the question?  I say this in all seriousness.  There's something "you guys" are getting at which escapes me.